# AS3: how to recursively trace all MovieClips that are on the stage

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, recursion, air

I have an Adobe Air project that has a number of MovieClips that can be added (via `addChild()`) or removed (via `removeChild()`).  For debugging purposes, I want to get a snapshot of all the MovieClips currently on the stage (visible or not).

The output should be in an indented tree-like format, show the MC names (if available), visibility status and the library object of which this MC is an instance.

The trace/debug function should be recursive, so as not to limit to a set number of levels.

Here is a sample output:

```
|1| featureStage     visible: true  [object MovieClip]
    |2| mcName1  visible: true  [object syndicationRHS_2]
    |2| mcName3  visible: false [object VideoScreen]
        |3| toolbox  visible: false [object toolboxMC_126]
            |4| bgColorImg   visible: true  [object MovieClip]
            |4| fontColorImg     visible: false [object MovieClip]
            |4| calendar     visible: false [object MovieClip]
        |3| tabDesign    visible: true  [object TabDesign_130]
        |3| designBox    visible: false [object MovieClip]
```

The project has multiple class (.as) files, and I want to be able to call this routine from anywhere in the project.

After searching for a while, I found some ideas that helped me create the answer below.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code.  It specifically looks for MovieClip objects, however it can be modified to look for other object types if needed. Hope this helps.

in the `main.as` class definition:

```
public var __childDepth:int;
```

And a public function in the same class module

```
public function showAllChildren(mc:MovieClip)
{
    var numC = mc.numChildren;
    var tabStr:String = "";

    for (var t = 0; t < __childDepth; t++)
    {
        tabStr = tabStr + "\t";
    }

    for(var i = 0; i < numC; i++)
    {
        var child = mc.getChildAt(i); 
        if (child is MovieClip) {
            trace (tabStr
                + '|' + __childDepth + '| ' + mc.getChildAt(i).name
                + '\t visible: ' + mc.getChildAt(i).visible
        //      + '\t type:' + typeof (mc.getChildAt(i))
                + '\t' + mc.getChildAt(i));
        }

        if (child is MovieClip && child.numChildren > 0)
        {
            __childDepth ++;
            showAllChildren (child);
            __childDepth --;
        }
    }
}
```

Then in another (or the same) class module:

```
objGrandParent.__childDepth = 1;
objGrandParent.showAllChildren(MovieClip(root));
```

Where `objGrandParent` is wherever you've declared `showAllChildren`.  In my case it was a parent of a parent that I am referencing.  I want to start displaying all the MCs starting from the stage, thus the MC passed to the function is `MovieClip(root)`.

Answer (score 0):

You should store references to everything in arrays for referencing.  You'll see that it clears up issues like these.

Here's example of storing buttons in an array:

```
var aButtons: Array = new Array();

for (var i = 0; i < aButtons.length; i++) {
    var mcNewButton: MyButton = new MyButton();
    mcButtons.addChild(mcNewButton);
    mcNewButton.x = i * 100;
    mcNewButton.iButtonID = i;
    mcNewButton.tMaintText.text = "Button " + i;
    mcNewButton.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, fButtonPress);
    aButtons.push(mcNewButton);
}

function fButtonPress(e:MouseEvent):void {
    trace("fButtonPress: iButtonID: " + e.target.iButtonID);
}
```

Then you can reference the properties like this:  aButtons[i].iButtonID

You'll see that all the code clears up including easily checking/setting properties like visible.

Comment: How would you determine the parent-child relationships of the movieClips using an array?  The intention of my code above was to be able to display all MCs at once and their parent-child relationship in a tree like fashion.  

My project frequently adds and removes children, sometimes moving (remove then add) it to another MC, so the structure can be quite dynamic.

Comment: You set the relationship so why do you need code to go back and set it again?  You should keep references to everything so there's never a need to use code to create references.